# Cancelling Fetch results in client being Disconnected

Tags: mailkit

When cancelling `IMailFolder.Fetch` method with the cancellationToken, I get an exception that the client is disconnected.

I debugged MailKit and traced the issue to `ImapEngine.Iterate()` method where there is the following:

```
try {
            while (current.Step ()) {
                // more literal data to send...
            }

            if (current.Bye)
                Disconnect ();
        } catch {
            Disconnect ();
            throw;
        } finally {
            current = null;
        }
```

Is it the right approach to disconnect the client on every exception type being caught?

Should this also apply to the case when we are cancelling the operation, so we can prioritize another operation, and we do not want to disconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How else would you cancel a command that is in progress if not disconnecting the socket?

Comment: You're right, I guess I didn't dive that deep in the code. So, in this case I should reconnect manually to the server?

Comment: Correct. But check the IsConnected state after getting a ProtocolException. IOException always means disconnected.